# MediaElement.js Wordpress Sidebar

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js, sidebar

I can put an audio clip in a post but have not been able to put one in a sidebar.  Is it possible to put a mp3 clip via MediaElement.js in a Wordpress Sidebar (I am using the Flexibility3 Theme).  Jim